# Make new array with value from other has some relation

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays

```
$array1 = array(
        "item1"=>array(
            "id1"=>1,
            "val"=>100,
        ),
        "item2"=>array(
            "id1"=>2,
            "val"=>300
        ),
        "item3"=>array(
            "id1"=>3,
            "val"=>400
        ),
        "item4"=>array(
            "id1"=>7,
            "val"=>150
        ),
        "item5"=>array(
            "id1"=>10,
            "val"=>200
        ),
        "item6"=>array(
            "id1"=>12,
            "val"=>900
        ),
    );
//sum of val = 2050
$array2 = array(
    "item1"=>array(
        "id2"=>7,
        "val"=>500,
    ),
    "item2"=>array(
        "id2"=>10,
        "val"=>150,
    ),
    "item3"=>array(
        "id2"=>15,
        "val"=>800,
    ),
    "item4"=>array(
        "id2"=>20,
        "val"=>600,
    ),
);
//sum of val = 2050
```

Now i want to create a new array like this

```
$array3 = array(
        "item1"=>array(
            "id"=>1,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 10, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item2"=>array(
            "id"=>2,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 30, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item3"=>array(
            "id"=>3,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 50, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item4"=>array(
            "id"=>4,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 100, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item5"=>array(
            "id"=>5,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 150, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item6"=>array(
            "id"=>6,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 210, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item7"=>array(
            "id"=>7,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 150, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item8"=>array(
            "id"=>8,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 300, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item9"=>array(
            "id"=>9,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 500, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item10"=>array(
            "id"=>10,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 100, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
        "item11"=>array(
            "id"=>11,
            "id1"=> id1,// (from array1)
            "id2"=> id2,// (from array2)
            "val"=> 450, // random integer (10,500)
        ),
    );
```

val is a random integer.
 The sum of val in array 3 needs to be equal to the sum of val in array 1.

**Example:**
value (val) of item1 in array1 = 100
and value (val) of item1 in array2 = 50
so that
if the value (val) of any children in array3 get from it with value 
maximum 100 
if get 100 from this value the id1 of this item will be present 1 times in array3
if get 50 its will present 2 times
I've tried for 2 days but I cannot do it.
Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your php array3. That is going to create problems.

Comment: An Array must have unique set of keys!

Comment: @Ngan Your logic of `val` calculation is confusing. Plus what exactly you are trying here? `$array1` has 6 values and `$array2` has 4 values but your `$array3` has 11 values, how?

Comment: Thanks @Shrikant Mavlankar. Example i have 2050 product i store in 6 warehouse (array1). i sale those product for 4 customer (array2) by 11 transaction (array3)

Comment: Okay but the arrays you've shown in above scenarios doesn't have any relation between them, so creating `$array3` using `$array1` and `$array2` is not possible, at least looking at your above scenario

Comment: relation via id(x) in each array, i need to store warehouse_id (id1) and customer_id (id2) to each transaction :)